# Class is Already defined but it still says class Not defined Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop, nameerror

Hello Currently i'm new to Python. Although i'have defined a class before using it. it still says name 'Person' is not defined

```
class Person:
    name = ""
    gender = ""

    def __init__(self, name, gender):
        self.name = name
        self.gender = gender

    ref = Person(11,22)
```

Comment: I guess you have indentation problem.

Comment: You instantiated `ref` in your class, thus it is not visible outside of it.

Comment: You can't have your reference to the class inside the class definition. The class doesn't exist until you've finished the class definition block.

Comment: Thanks Got it ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an indentation problem in your class definition, you need to move **ref = Person(11,22)** away from **class Person:** scope, Like this:

```
class Person:
    name = ""
    gender = ""

    def __init__(self, name, gender):
        self.name = name
        self.gender = gender


ref = Person(11,22)
```